# MDX How to add bands to grouped fact table

Tags: range, ssas, grouping, mdx, cube

I'm trying to create income bands on my fact table.

The fact table that consists of

Date, TranType, AdvKey, Amount

```
01/01/2015 TRAN1 ID01 5000 
01/02/2015 TRAN1 ID02 13000 
01/03/2015 TRAN2 ID01 500
```

The AdvKey links back to DimIFADetails, this table has a ParentKey, a Parent Child hierarchy. There are two levels, Adviser and Adviser Group

```
ADVKEY PARENTKEY 
----------------
ID01    ID03  
ID02    ID03 
ID03    NULL
```

I want to be able to group on AdvKey or AdvGrpKey and have the summed amounts (income) allocated to income bands.

So when I group on Adviser, each adviser will be assigned an income band, ie 0-10k, 10-50k, 50-100k, same applies when the grouping is changed to the Group Level.
In the above

```
ID01 5300   0-10000 
ID02 13000  10000-20000
```

or if by Adviser Group

```
ID03 18300  10000-20000
```

In SQL, I could group by the key necessary, then add a column and case statement to allocate each aggregated amount to a band.

The facttable has about 2 million rows.

The income is how much is generated from the advisers and adviser group, so this will change over time.

I can't think of any way to do it with a dimension, as there is no way to link back to the fact table seeing as these are groupings done at run time.

---

I now have something that works

```
with 
 MEMBER Measures.[Calc Sum] as
      IIF(  Sum(EXISTING [Dim IFA Details].[Parent Key].[Adviser Group].Members,
            Measures.[Amount] * -1
        ) <= 10000 , '0-10000', IIF(  Sum(EXISTING [Dim IFA Details].[Parent Key].[Adviser Group].Members,
            Measures.[Amount] * -1
        ) <= 20000 , '10001 - 20000' , '>20000' ))

SELECT   { [Measures].[Amount] , measures.[Calc Sum] } 
ON COLUMNS, 
NONEMPTY( [Dim IFA Details].[Parent Key].[Adviser Group].Members , [Measures].[Amount])
on rows
FROM [Income and Emails Cube]
```

Its going to have a rather bulky IIF when I add more bands.
Is it possible to create a dimension with the categories and add the keys on the fly like this? 
or would there be no benefit.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve this in MDX, but more details are required for us to solve it.  What is the cube design in place? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried some dynamic ranges I got from msdn, that gave me a bunch of ranges and summed it, not quite what I wanted. The cube is just that, the fact table with advkey, and that links to the dimension table which has a parent child relationship in it. I am trying to use the parentkey group and then group that further into bands. My mdx knowledge is minimal, so I'm kinda stuck as to what to try. And my googling has not yielded much maybe I'm not searching on the right things...